# Java Date Comparison

Tags: java, date, date-comparison

I am trying to compare dates using java.util.Date and also java.util.Calendar but for some reason I do not seem to get the correct result. My code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String currentDate = "2014-10-04";
String startDate = "2014-07-08";
String endDate = "2015-02-28";
Calendar cDate = Calendar.getInstance();  
cDate.setTime(df.parse(currentDate));
Calendar sDate = Calendar.getInstance();  
sDate.setTime(df.parse(startDate));
Calendar eDate = Calendar.getInstance();  
eDate.setTime(df.parse(endDate));
System.out.println(cDate.compareTo(sDate));
System.out.println(cDate.after(sDate));
```

As you can see the after should return true but it returns false.

Comment: `mm` is for minutes. `MM` is for months.

Comment: @Vicky Don't make code corrections that invalidate the question.

Comment: You also don't need to use Calendar. You can just do: `Date cDate = df.parse(currentDate);`, etc. and then do the same comparison on `cDate.after(sDate)`

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yup, answers should be posted as answers, not as edits to the question. :)

Comment: I put it back, but hope she didn't do it to any other questions as well lol

Comment: Take care about SimpleDateFormat, its not threadsave.

Comment: Comparing `Dates` in Java is not well build and most people in this case would use `Joda DateTime` to do so. Here a link to the website: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: @BilltheLizard: When I did code correction, I did not know the mistake was intentional. I thought its a typo.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

Your pattern for `SimpledateFormat` is incorrect: `mm` specifies the minute of the day. Use `yyyy-MM-dd` and it works.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you fix the problem changing "yyyy-mm-dd" to "yyyy-MM-dd" as previously answered.

I run the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String currentDate = "2014-10-04";
        String startDate = "2014-07-08";
        String endDate = "2015-02-28";
        Calendar cDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        cDate.setTime(df.parse(currentDate));
        Calendar sDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        sDate.setTime(df.parse(startDate));
        Calendar eDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        eDate.setTime(df.parse(endDate));
        System.out.println(cDate.compareTo(sDate));
        System.out.println(cDate.after(sDate));
    }
```

And result was:

```
1
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your SimpleDateFormat pattern: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
M   Month in year   
m   Minute in hour
```

In your code:

```
cDate = 2014-01-04 00:10:00
sDate = 2014-01-08 00:07:00
```

You should use:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange                      // Represents a pair of `LocalDate` objects as a date range.
.of(
    LocalDate.parse( "2014-07-08" ) ,                  // Parse your input strings. The standard ISO 8601 format is used by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.
    LocalDate.parse( "2015-02-28" ) 
)                                                      // Returns a `LocalDateRange` object.
.contains(
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )   // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region.
)                                                      // Returns boolean primitive.
```

> false

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date`/`Calendar`.

Also, you are using date-with-time types to represent a date-only value. Instead, use the `LocalDate` date-only class.

### Today

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone][2] explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
```

### Comparing

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2014-07-08" ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( "2015-02-28" ) ;
```

Compare with the `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual` methods.

Use Half-Open approach (beginning is *inclusive*, while ending is *exclusive*) to define the span-of-time.

```
Boolean contains = ( ! today.isBefore( start ) ) && today.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

### `LocalDateRange`

If doing much of this work, add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project. This gives you the [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class.

```
LocalDateRange range = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;
Boolean contains = range.contains( today ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).